# TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON --> starting at object with constructor 'Socket'

Tags: node.js, express, backend, web-development-server, flash-message

I am trying to flash a message using expressjs module.
my app.js is as follows:-

```
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const flash = require('flash');
  
const app = express();

require('flatted');

// CJS
const {parse, stringify} = require('flatted');

// const express = require('express');
// const session = require('express-session');
// const flash = require('connect-flash');
  
// const app = express();
  
const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;
  
app.use(session({
    secret:'geeksforgeeks',
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true
}));
  
app.use(flash());
   
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  req.flash('message', 'Success!!');
  res.redirect('/gfg');
});
  
app.get('/gfg', (req, res) => {
    res.send((req.flash('message')));
});
  
app.listen(port, (err) => {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  console.log('Server is up and listening on', port);
});
```

I am getting the above mentioned error. I am new to nodejs, can someone tell me how to convert circular structure to JSON when flashing a message in express ?

Comment: the above code is taken from the [link] (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-display-flash-messages-using-connect-flash-module-in-node-js/)

Comment: ok, got it, using connect-flash instead of using flash in 3rd line solved the error